# Pcap open an interface and inject packets

Tags: c, pcap, libpcap, tcpreplay

I need to write a program in C to read in pcap files and extract the packets and send them out . It's like a traffic replay. I know there's tcpreplay but I didn't see its C library, it seems to be only a command-line application.

I know how to do it with pcap_open(), but it's only available in WinPcap, I need to do it in linux with libpcap. Anybody can provide some hint? Thanks in advance.

edit: I can parse the packets, but now I just don't know how to open an interface to send the packets out. Thanks.

Comment: see `pcap_open_offline` from [pcap man page](http://www.manpages.info/linux/pcap.3.html)

Comment: @SleuthEye I can parse the packets, but now I just don't know how to open an interface to send the packets out. Thanks.

Comment: Open as usual, for sending see `pcap_inject`.

Comment: @moorray use which function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `pcap_open_live()` or, in newer versions of libpcap, `pcap_create()` and `pcap_activate()` - all of which are available in the current version of WinPcap, by the way.